# effective and annual interest rate compounded monthly?

Tags: interest-rate

I just started my Enginnering Economic and I met this question in my quiz

> PromInvest Inc. invested 5.5 million in a project ten years ago. As of
> today the worth of this project is 24.7 million. What annual interest
> rate has the project been earning if interest is compounded monthly?

This was how I tried to do it but the answer was wrong

24.7/5.5=4.49
120√4.49=1.012
(1.012)^12=0.162=16.2%

The other options are 14.2%, 14.8%, 15.8%, 15.2%.
Which one is correct and how to get it?

Comment: Who knows?  More precisely $\sqrt[120]{4.4909}\approx 1.012596$. Your attempt of $1.012596^{12}\approx 1.162$ so $16.2\%$ looks plausible while other possibilities include $12 \times 0.012596 \approx 0.15115$ so $15.1\%$ or $\log_e(1.012596^{12})\approx 0.1502$ so about $15.0\%$ are not in the list of options

Comment: Solving this for the formula of future value also procured me with the coveted *16.2* therefore this is a bum.

Comment: All I can think of is to multiply the monthly interest rate by 12. It’s close to 15.2%. This matches how a bond with monthly coupon payments would be quoted. (The annual rate of return is greater than the coupon rate for bonds with more than one annual coupon.)